# LNK2019 cuda::cvtColor and cuda::equalizeHist

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to use `cuda::cvtColor` and `cuda::equalizeHist` but I get errors as follows:

`Error  LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::cuda::cvtColor(class cv::debug_build_guard::_InputArray const &,class cv::debug_build_guard::_OutputArray const &,int,int,class cv::cuda::Stream &)" (?cvtColor@cuda@cv@@YAXAEBV_InputArray@debug_build_guard@2@AEBV_OutputArray@42@HHAEAVStream@12@@Z) referenced in function "class cv::Mat __cdecl edgedetect(class cv::Mat,double,double)" (?edgedetect@@YA?AVMat@cv@@V12@NN@Z)    ConsoleApplication2`

and likewise for `equalizeHist`. I guess I'm missing some libs or maybe headers, have you got any idea which ones?

Win10 x64, CUDA 10.0, OpenCV 4.0.0, MVS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Please show your compile and link command. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the linker if you have linked CUDA correctly. cuda::cvtColor and cuda::equalizeHist are under cuda imgproc.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you!